# how to fix firefox command line arguments launched by the start menu's search box?

Tags: windows-7, firefox, command-line, start-menu

Another little, but annoying and not understandable issue on my computer:

If I use the start menu's search box to launch firefox with command line arguments (e.g. -p -no-remote) but without its full path, firefox is launched without arguments...

And on the other side, if I use the run box (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) I don't need the full path and the arguments are used. And if I use another command line (e.g. cmd /K ipconfig) in the start menu's search box there's no problem either...

As far as I remember it's not the normal behavior. And reinstalling doesn't fix it, so how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found that if I **add the extension (.exe)** it works

So I will use:

```
firefox.exe -p -no-remote
```

and not:

```
firefox -p -no-remote
```

I also found that if I **remove all the shortcuts from the start menu** it works too (without the ".exe")

Additional note: I think the search box use this registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe` to find it

It leads to other questions:  Which places exactly are used to launch programs from the search box? In what preference order? Is it possible to configure this order?

Comment: I believe it does it in the order of one's path, and also finds .lnk files, too.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: create a batch file (.bat or .cmd) in the Firefox folder that'll do this for you:

#### firefox.bat (or firefox.cmd)

```
firefox.exe -p -no-remote
```

Would the search-box find this script? (I don't have Win7 so I can't check).

Comment: No, the search-box doesn't find the batch file. I think it only looks in the start menu shortcuts, path (variable environment) and some registry keys. I could simply create a shortcut with the arguments built-in but I want to keep the modularity of the use of arguments